# Optional Ant arg

Tags: ant, properties, arguments

I would like to have an ant arg value optionally included without having to make 2 targets which would be basically the same except for the extra arg. For example:

```
<target name="A" depends="C">...</target>

<target name="B" depends="C">...</target>

<target name="C">
    <java fork="true" ...>
        <jvmarg .../>
        <arg .../>
        <arg .../>
        ...
        # now, if the dependency is from A, no more args
        # if from B
            <arg value="xxx"/>
    </java>
</target>
```

Comment: you could try the 'unless' statement. I'm kinda new to ant myself, so not sure if this will work for args, but for many tasks it does. Looks like : <target name="x" depends="y" unless="args.allset"> args.allset is a property you can define as 'true' in one target and 'false' in another

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rather than `depend`ing on task C, you could use the [Antcall](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/antcall.html) task to pass the `B` argument as a `param`.

```
<target name="A" >
  <antcall target="C" />
  ....
</target>

<target name="B" >
  <antcall target="C" >
    <param name="extra_arg" value="xxx" />
  </antcall>
  ...
</target>

<target name="C">
    <java fork="true" ...>
        <jvmarg .../>
        <arg .../>
        <arg .../>
        <arg value="${extra_arg}"/>
    </java>
</target>
```

EDIT: As Nico points out in the comment, this doesn't work if the value is unset from A. The answer can be extended to use the `condition` task to set the argument to a null string.

```
<condition property="argToUseIfFromB" else="">
  <isset property="extra_arg" />      
</condition>
<java fork="true" ...>
    <jvmarg .../>
    <arg .../>
    <arg .../>
    <arg value="${argToUseIfFromB}"/>
</java>
```

FURTHER EDIT: 
Since we can't get the arguments to be recognised as optional, we can pass in the whole command line from each parent task. Target `A` would only pass the common arguments; `B` would pass through an extra argument. The Ant manual on [arguments](http://ant.apache.org/manual/using.html#arg) explains it better than me.

```
<target name="A" >
  <antcall target="C">
    <param name="java_args" value="arg_a arg_b" /> 
  </antcall>
  ....
</target>

<target name="B" >
  <antcall target="C" >
    <param name="java_args" value="arg_a arg_b extra_arg" />
  </antcall>
  ...
</target>

<target name="C">
    <java fork="true" ...>
        <jvmarg .../>
        <arg line="${java_args}"/>
    </java>
</target>
```

Comment: Nope, this does not work. When A calls C it will throw an error, since no *extra_arg* has been defined at that stage. Works fine when B calls C.

Comment: Still no. It does the same as your original. Saying that '' is not a valid argument. Seems even if it's null it still tries to force it as an argument.

Comment: @Nico - In which case, how about we go for the simpler option. Set *all* the args as parameters to C, and just pass a subset from A?

Comment: That would probably end up being the answer. Please edit your answer then I'll accept it as correct. I couldn't find any other way either.