# Optional parameter to <ant> task call?

Tags: ant, ant-contrib

I would like to be able to pass an optional parameter to an ant task call, so that it appears as unset to the called target if it is omitted (important in conditions or when using the `unless` or `if` attributes). I don't know if *optArg* is set, so I cannot hard-code the parameter.

Example: The ant target *someTarget* requires a mandatory parameter *mandatoryArg* and supports an optional parameter *optArg*.

I can achieve this by cludgy duplication like so:

```
<if><equals arg1="${optArg}" arg2="true" />
    <then>
        <ant dir="someDir" target="someTarget" inheritAll="false">
            <property name="mandatoryArg" value="42" />
            <property name="optArg" value="true" />
        </ant>
    </then>
    <else>
        <ant dir="someDir" target="someTarget" inheritAll="false">
            <property name="mandatoryArg" value="42" />
        </ant>
    </else>
</if>
```

I would like to leave out the if statement so that the ant call is not duplicated, without losing the optional nature of *optArg*. I already found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5114824/optional-ant-arg), which appears to cover a different problem.

I use Ant 1.7 and ant-contrib.

Any ideas? Thanks!

EDIT: I also accept answers that explain why it really isn't possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might be able to get the behavior you want by using the `<if>` block to build a property set, and then referencing it inside a single `<ant>` task call later with `<propertyset refid="whatever"/>`

Comment: make sure to enclose code snippets in backticks `like this` so your code will be visible.  Cheers~

Comment: @David: Sounds promising, but how would I go about adding to the propertyset, then? Could you provide a code sample? Thanks!

Comment: Ok, found out by myself. You define a propertyset containing mandatoryArg *and* optArg that's dynamically evaluated every time it's referenced. Then, when the antcall occurs, it contains only the properties which are actually defined. So I'll accept the answer.